# Django - keeping parameters dictionary between requests

Tags: django

I need to show a table according to some parameters, like registers per page or other criterias. How can I easily manage it with Django templates? I know that parameter of GET requests are in the form of query strings.

I have two distincts buttons

```
<a href="{% url 'create_company' %}?regs=25">

<a href="{% url 'create_company' %}?status=active">
```

How can I make them behave like

```
<a href="{% url 'create_company' %}<whatever was here before plus>status=active">
```

as so if I click the first one, receive the page and click the second one, the final result would be

```
<a href="{% url 'create_company' %}?regs=25&status=active">
```

likewise if I change the combobox of regs from 25 to 10, it know it has to remove regs=25 and add regs=10

Comment: What do you have right now? Any example code?

Comment: @KevinLonde changed original question

Comment: You could use this snippet: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1627/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a custom solution

```
# my_tags.py
@register.tag
def query_string(parser, token):
    """Converts a string into all lowercase"""
    tag_name, dic, key, value = token.split_contents()
    return QueryStringNode(dic, key, value)


class QueryStringNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, dic, key, value):
        self.dic = template.Variable(dic)
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            actual_dic = self.dic.resolve(context)
            actual_dic[self.key] = self.value
            return '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(actual_dic)
        except VariableDoesNotExist: # allows no dic at all to blank links
            actual_dic = {self.key: self.value}
            return '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(actual_dic)
```

and on the template

```
<a href="{% url 'create_company' %}{% query_string params 'test' '1' %}">link</a>
```

The inconvenience is that in every view I have to parse all querystrings, put them back into a dictionary, and render to response with the dictionary as 'params'